# Why does a Required IdentityUser property result in a nullable database field?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations, data-annotations

I want to require that all entities of a particular type have a corresponding user in my ASP.NET MVC app, and that this is enforced at the database level i.e. as a non-nullable field. However, when I set the `Required` attribute on the `IdentityUser` property in my model class, like so:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Test.Models
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public IdentityUser User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

the corresponding migration that gets generated sets the `UserId` table field to nullable:

```cs
UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true)
```

I've read that Table Per Hierarchy can cause this, but I'm not using any kind of inheritance.

What am I missing? Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Does it work when you explicitly set the property as required in `DbContext.OnModelConfiguring`?

Comment: Can you show the whole class pls?

Comment: @abdusco I can't find any reference to an `OnModelConfiguring` in the API documentation.

Comment: @Serge I've added the entire class code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to fix your class

```
public class Foo
    { 
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
       [Required]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

       [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
        public IdentityUser User { get; set; }
    }
```

Net 5 automatically creates a shadow property UserId in order you could save your Foo class.  Since you used [Required], EF automatically added that it is nullable. If this property was not able to be null (for example if it was  int type ( not int? ! ))  you would not need a [Required] attribute.

Comment: The IdentityUser primary key is a string, not an int.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know why the extra property is required? Why can't I just put the `Required` attribute on `User` and it works?

Comment: @SimonMorgan Because you can not  save the whole User record  in a Foo database table.  You can only save one column value.  To save a primary key is the best way to find User when you need to join. Net 5 can create a shadow property UserId but it always better to keep it under control.

Comment: But even without the `UserId` property, EF figures out that it's a foreign key to the AspNetUsers table and creates a `UserId` field on the Foo table, but it sets it as nullable even though the `User` property is `[Required]`. So how come you have to explicitly add a `UserId` property to the model and set *that* as `[Required]` for it to set the database `UserId` field as non-nullable?

Comment: Yes ,  As I told already  it is called a shadow property and it is usefull for saving only. But it always better to add it explicitly in order you coud use it in your code. You will not need to include the whole user record if you only need a userId for example.

Answer (score -1):

Also what you can do is to use [Fluent API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships) to configure your contraints.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public IdentityUser User { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.User)
            .WithMany(d => d.Foos)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId);
    }
}
```